# Nueva fila con datos Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un scrip en GAS para procesar información de una hoja de cálculo (viene de un formulario) y agregarla a otras hojas.

Solo consigo que agrege una nueva fila pero no que agrege los datos.

Y no genera ningún error simplemente agrega una nueva fila pero ahí acaba, es como si la parte Agregar datos no estubiera.

Obtener datos:

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LOG-"+year)
      var valor = ss.getMaxRows()
    
      var Fecha = ss.getRange("C"+valor).getValue()
     
      var CtaOrigen = ss.getRange("D"+valor).getDisplayValue()
      if (CtaOrigen == "A") { var Origen = "B" }
      if (CtaOrigen == "B") { var Origen = "C" }
    
      var CtaDestino = ss.getRange("E"+valor).getDisplayValue()
      if (CtaDestino == "A") { var Origen = "B" }
      if (CtaDestino == "B") { var Origen = "C" }
      
      var Descripcion = ss.getRange("F"+valor).getDisplayValue()
    
      var Puntos = ss.getRange("G"+valor).getDisplayValue()
      if (Puntos == "Interno - Interno") { var Puntos = "INT" }
      if (Puntos == "Externo - Interno") { var Puntos = "EXT" }
      if (Puntos == "Interno - Externo") { var Puntos = "INT" }
   
      var Importe = ss.getRange("H"+valor).getDisplayValue()
```

Nueva fila

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Origen)
  var valor = ss.getMaxRows()  
  ss.insertRowsAfter(valor, 1)
```

Agregar datos a nueva fila

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Origen)
  var valor = ss.getMaxRows()
  
  spreadsheetlog.getRange("A"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(Fecha)

  spreadsheetlog.getRange("B"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(Descripcion)

  spreadsheetlog.getRange("C"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(Origen)

  spreadsheetlog.getRange("D"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(CtaOrigen)

  spreadsheetlog.getRange("E"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(Destino)

  spreadsheetlog.getRange("F"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(CtaDestino)
```

He definido las variables manualmente

```
  var Fecha = "15/01/2020"
  var Origen = "123456789"
  var Destino = "987654321"
  var Descripcion = "EJEMPLO OPERACION"
  var Puntos = "INT"
  var Importe = "15,21"
```

Y tampoco agrega datos
[image: Resultado en la hora de calculo, solo agrega filas pero vacias]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Cuando un código no funciona usualmente se sugiere incluir un [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estas implementando correctamente la escritura en una hoja de cálculo con Google Apps Script.

```
spreadsheetlog.getRange("A"+valor).activate();
spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(Fecha)
```

Dudo mucho que le de tiempo a enterarse de cual es la celda actual y poder setear el valor.

1. La forma correcta para escribir una celda sería:

```
spreadsheetlog.getRange("A"+valor).setValue(Fecha);
```

2. Ahora bien, esto sería un poco ineficiente. La forma de escribir toda una fila seria usando un rango entero:

```
var temp = new Array();
temp.push(Fecha);
temp.push(Descripcion);
etc etc etc
```

//Esto se debe hacer por que los rangos son matrices bidimensionales

```
var out = new Array();
out.push(temp);

spreadsheetlog.getRange(1,valor,1,temp.length).setValues(out);
```

3. Si quieres, puedes hacerlo mejor y usar directamente la función appendRow

```
spreadsheetlog.appendRow(temp);
```

Fijate que en esta opción lo que le pasamos es un vector de datos, no una matriz como al usar el getRange.

Te recomiendo algunos links para que puedas afianzar un poco mejor estos temas:

1. Como [obtener un rango](https://www.tutorialesgoogleappscripts.com/2020/09/obtener-rango-google-apps-script.html)
2. Como [escribir un rango](https://www.tutorialesgoogleappscripts.com/2016/04/como-optimizar-la-escritura-en.html)
3. Ejemplo de [appendRow](https://www.tutorialesgoogleappscripts.com/2020/08/como-anadir-fila-spreadsheet-google-script.html)

Answer (score 0):

Me he dado cuenta del fallo y además es evidente

`spreadsheetlog.` debería haber sido `ss.`

Esto:

```
  spreadsheetlog.getRange("A"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(Fecha)

  spreadsheetlog.getRange("B"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(Descripcion)

  spreadsheetlog.getRange("C"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(Origen)

  spreadsheetlog.getRange("D"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(CtaOrigen)

  spreadsheetlog.getRange("E"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(Destino)

  spreadsheetlog.getRange("F"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(CtaDestino)
```

Debería ser:

```
  ss.getRange("A"+valor).activate();
  ss.getCurrentCell().setValue(Fecha)

  ss.getRange("B"+valor).activate();
  ss.getCurrentCell().setValue(Descripcion)

  ss.getRange("C"+valor).activate();
  ss.getCurrentCell().setValue(Origen)

  ss.getRange("D"+valor).activate();
  ss.getCurrentCell().setValue(CtaOrigen)

  ss.getRange("E"+valor).activate();
  spreadsheetlog.getCurrentCell().setValue(Destino)

  ss.getRange("F"+valor).activate();
  ss.getCurrentCell().setValue(CtaDestino)
```

Comment: Es muy ineficiente activar una celda a la vez para luego agrearle un valor a dicha celda. Puedes agregar todos los valores en una sóla instrucción suando `setValues(values)`. Si quieres ir de a poco, en lugar de `ss.getRange("A"+valor).activate();
  ss.getCurrentCell().setValue(Fecha)` usa `ss.getRange("A"+valor).setValue(Fecha)`